# When solving for $\sin$ or $\cos(2t)$ given $\sin$ or $\cos(t)$ is the quadrant relevant?

Tags: trigonometry

I notice some of the homework problems in my book ask me to find the sine or cosine of twice an angle given the sine or cosine of the angle. They also mention $P(t)$ is in some given quadrant.

My question is, wouldn't the answer be the same regardless of which quadrant $P(t)$ is in? I suspect this is just the book's way of trying to throw me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadrant is relevant.  Consider the following examples.

**Example 1.**  Find $\sin(2\theta)$ if $\sin\theta = \dfrac{3}{5}$ and $\theta$ is a first quadrant angle.

**Solution.**  Since $\theta$ is a first quadrant angle, $\cos\theta > 0$.  Thus, 
$$\cos\theta = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta} = \frac{4}{5}$$
Hence, 
$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = 2\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) = \frac{24}{25}$$

**Example 2.** Find $\sin(2\theta)$ if $\sin\theta = \dfrac{3}{5}$ and $\theta$ is a second quadrant angle.

**Solution.**  Since $\theta$ is a second quadrant angle, $\cos\theta < 0$. Thus, 
$$\cos\theta = -\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta} = -\frac{4}{5}$$
Hence, 
$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = 2\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right) = -\frac{24}{25}$$

Notice that the only difference in the statement of examples 1 and 2 is the quadrant of the angle $\theta$.  Hence, the reason we obtained values with different signs was due solely to the quadrant of the angle.

On the other hand, the double angle formulas for cosine 
\begin{align*}
\cos(2\theta) & = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta\\
              & = 2\cos^2\theta - 1\\
              & = 1 - 2\sin^2\theta
\end{align*}
depend on the squares of sine and/or cosine, so the value of $\cos(2\theta)$ does not depend on the quadrant of the angle.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the quadrant. A simplified way to think about it is that $\cos(x)$ has the sign of the $x$-coordinate and $\sin(x)$ has the sign of the $y$-coordinate. For example, the sign of cosine in quadrant one is positive but the sign of cosine in the third quadrant is negative due to the sign of the $x$-axis in each quadrant.